# jQuery—Checking URL for String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set up a jQuery script to control the appearance the advanced section of a search form. If a search hasn't been submitted, the `div` containing the advanced search should remain hidden. But if a search has been submitted as designated by the URL containing the string "Search", show the advanced search `div`.

The problem I'm seeing is that no matter what's in the URL it's always showing the `#advsearch div` through a fade in. It never returns false. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("Search")) {
$('#advsearch').fadeIn()
}
else {
    $('#adv').click(function() {
    $('#advsearch').slideDown()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the string **cannot** be found, [**`indexOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns `-1`, which evaluates to `true`.

Do:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("Search") > -1)
```

---

Depending on where the string is in the URL, you might just want to search in the `pathName`, `search` or `hash` part of the URL. Have a look at the [documentation of the `location` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).

Comment: And while this will never be the case in a URL, it returns 0 (which evaluates to false) if the match starts with the first character of the string